# How to use `withr::defer()` instead of `testthat::setup()` in R?

Tags: r, unit-testing, tidyverse, testthat

I would like to understand what are the current alternatives to `setup()` and `teardown()` in `testthat` 3rd edition. I found [this blog post](https://testthat.r-lib.org/articles/test-fixtures.html) where it is discussed that `setup()` and `teardown()` are deprecated in favour of **test fixures**.

I checked that post and another recommended one (i.e., [this one](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/self-cleaning-test-fixtures/)),
and the recommendation is to use `withr::defer()`. However, I don't fully get it.

Suppose I two simple tests. Each test relies on getting some external resources, then performs a check.

```r
# First test.
test_that("..." {
    # Super long process to get this data.
    data <- matrix(rnorm(9), 3, 3)

    # My test.
    expect_equal(nrow(data), 3)
})

# Second test.
test_that("..." {
    # Super long process to get this data.
    data <- matrix(rnorm(9), 3, 3)

    # My test.
    expect_equal(ncol(data), 3)
})
```

Normally, I would use `setup()` to perform the intensive process that generates the `data` object and ensure that this object is available for all tests in that file. Something like this:

```r
setup({
    # Super long process to get this data.
    data <- matrix(rnorm(9), 3, 3)
})
```

Then, I would carry on with my tests.

```r
# First test.
test_that("..." {
    expect_equal(nrow(data), 3)
})

# Second test.
test_that("..." {
    expect_equal(ncol(data), 3)
})
```

For the sake of this question, let's assume that I can't squash the two tests together.
How can I use `withr::defer()` to achieve the same behavior as `setup()` above?